# Enable Wordpress WP_DEBUG', true,false using API?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to build a site which can manage my wordpress site. I am looking into a feature where with a click on button I should be able to enable wordpress debug flags like
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); or define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', False ); I am looking if there is a way I can leverage REST API to enable this feature?

Comment: Those are defined very early in the [WordPress process](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/53096e67966883f78135ef62005dcc5386bcd191/wp-includes/default-constants.php#L91). If this we're my project, I would probably have an `include` in wp-config.php that loads something to set those variables, and use my plugin to write to that file using the REST endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I am pretty sure I will be able to do it in the way you have suggested. I am just thinking if there is way any add on plugin.

Comment: Another way that I just thought of, which might be overly complicated but has usages, is to set those constants to environment variables. Then, if you are in an Apache environment, you could tweak .htaccess with [`SetEnv`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html) calls. WordPress actually has special functions for [writing](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/insert_with_markers/) and [reading](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/extract_from_markers/) that file and surrounding with BEGIN/END comments.

Comment: The current request wouldn't have those set, but all subsequent ones would.

Comment: I will be using Nginx I will see if we can implement similar approach

Comment: I'm Nginx, too, and I don't think you'll be able to do it as easily unfortunately. Or if you do, it will be basically the same as my other suggestion, just writing to an arbitrary files. Nginx's config is all compiled, so you'd have to cycle the process, and possibly PHP-FPM, too, to affect it. But good luck, and let us know what you were able to do, if you can!